# How to force a sympy function to be re-evaluated every time

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I want to create a function in sympy, which should output the value from the array if it is not nan else remain unevaluated.

This is how I done

```py
u = np.zeros((steps+1, cons['m']+1), dtype='float')
u[:, :] = np.nan
u[:, 0] = 0
u[0, 1:-1] = 1
u[:, -1] = 0

class U(smp.Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, i, j):
        global u
        print('it runs!') # printing this to explain the problem
        if isinstance(i, smp.Integer) and isinstance(j, smp.Integer):
            if not np.isnan(u[i, j]):
                return u[i, j]
```

this is what the numpy array look like

```py
u[:3]
```

output:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.],
       [ 0., nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,  0.]])
```

the problem is every time a function is called with some args, the output is stored in the memory and when I call the same function with exact same args, it just outputs the value from the memory instead of running the program again.

```py
U(2, 1)
```

output:

```
it runs!
U(2, 1)
```

then I try this on the next cell

```py
u[2, 1] = 2
U(2, 1)
```

output:

```
U(2, 1)
```

Look "it runs!" is not printed. I want "2" as the output.
I learnt about custom function from [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/custom-functions.html#creating-a-custom-function).

when I run this

```
u[4, 4] = 10
U(4, 4)
```

output:

```
it runs!
10
```

since this is the first time (4, 4) is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following demonstrates that `clear_cache` will work (though it arbitrarily uses a different definition for `u`):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It works fine. I didn't encounter arbitrary change in u.

Comment: Glad it worked. (I changed the definition of `u` is what I meant; I didn't use your definition.)